# Check if an element is a property of an object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable, for example `myVariable.value = "text"`

And an array of objects of this form:

```
[{name: "1", value: "word"},
 {name: "2", value: "text"},
 {name: "3", value: "xyz"}
]
```

I want to find out if  `myVariable.value` is available as a `value`property of an object in the array, nothing else. Just get true if it is or false if it isn't in the array.

I found something here like:

```
var aa = {hello: "world"};
alert( aa["hello"] );      // popup box with "world"
alert( aa["goodbye"] );    // popup box with "undefined"
```

but I don't know how to do it for an array of objects. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to iterate the array, probably best using `.includes`.

Comment: `!!array.find(o => o.value === myVal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find the value in the array.

```js
let data = [{name: "1", value: "word"},
 {name: "2", value: "text"},
 {name: "3", value: "xyz"}
]

function findValue(value) {
  return data.some(item => item.value === value);
}

console.log(findValue('text'));
console.log(findValue('another'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just get true if it is or false if it isn't in the array.
>
> but I don't know how to do it for an array of objects. Any
>   suggestions?

Use `some` and `includes`

```
var valueToFind = "text";
var isAvailable = arr.some( s => Object.values( s ).includes( valueToFind ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "1",
    value: "word"
  },
  {
    name: "2",
    value: "text"
  },
  {
    name: "3",
    value: "xyz"
  }
];
var valueToFind = "text";
var isAvailable = arr.some( s =>  Object.values(s).includes( valueToFind ) );
console.log(isAvailable);
```

Convert this to a function

```
var fnCheckVal = ( arr, valueToFind ) => arr.some( s => Object.values(s).includes(valueToFind) );

console.log( fnCheckVal ( arr, "text" ) );
console.log( fnCheckVal ( arr, "word" ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "1",
    value: "word"
  },
  {
    name: "2",
    value: "text"
  },
  {
    name: "3",
    value: "xyz"
  }
];
var fnCheckVal = ( arr, valueToFind ) => arr.some( s => Object.values(s).includes(valueToFind) );

console.log( fnCheckVal ( arr, "text" ) );
console.log( fnCheckVal ( arr, "word" ) );
console.log( fnCheckVal ( arr, "valueDoesn'tExists" ) );
```

Comment: You may use `includes` instead of `indexOf`.

Comment: `arr.some( s => Object.values( s ).includes( valueToFind ) )` -- this unnecessarily creates `n^2` complexity due to inner loop.

Comment: @31piy You are right. If the OP's data-structure only contains only key-value in an object then your answer is more optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array `find` function for this kind of thing, here is an example:

```js
var arr = [{name: "1", value: "word"},
 {name: "2", value: "text"},
 {name: "3", value: "xyz"}
];

var toFind = {value: "word"};
var foundObject = arr.find(v => v.value == toFind.value);

console.log(foundObject);
```